# Python: What is the type of some_string[0:3]?

Tags: python

I have the following python code that does a string comparison:

```
>>> mf="moo foo"

>>> mf[0:3]
'moo'

>>> mf[0:3] is "moo"
False

>>> mf[0:3] == "moo"
True

>>> str(mf[0:3]) is "moo"
False
```

So the double equals operator returns true, but the python `is` operator returns false. This must be because they are not the same object.

What is the technical difference between a sequence of characters obtained with `str[n:m]` and a literal representation (`'moofoo'`) of the same string?  Why are they not the same object?

Comment: Part of the confusion here is due to Java's String. A "string" remains the same object more or less regardless of the method used to obtain "string".

Comment: Uh... nope. Not even in Java. Try it: `System.out.println("bobcat".substring(0, 3) == "bob");`

Comment: Two strings representing the same sequence of characters may or may not be the same object. This is true in both Python and Java.

Comment: Your title, _"Python: What is the type of some_string[0:3]?"_ doesn't match the content of your question. This is actually a question about the equality and identity operators, which has been asked before.

Comment: @MattH If you say so. @{user2357112}: Indeed. I guess the *opposite meaning* of == threw me off. Anyway, I'm good now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` tests for equality as well as the same object ID (In CPython, this is the address of the object in memory). `str(...)` and slicing creates a shallow copy and hence the `is` test fails.

`==` tests for equal values. `is` tests for object identity.

Quoted from [Python's Mailing List](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2002-April/013932.html)

> 'is' allows us to make the distinction if the system is keeping track
>   of two things that just look alike, or are actually the same thing.

Comment: Shallow copy meaning a new temporary reference or object? What's an object ID? Is it the same as an object reference? --- edit --- alright, given those terms I can google the details. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You can get the Object ID by doing `id(var)`.

Comment: A shallow copy creates a new object and then inserts references to the nested objects into it.